# C# Как сохранить exe файла в переменную?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Подскажите метод для загрузки файла(именно EXE файла) в программу, чтобы он сохранялся в переменную

Comment: `byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\program.exe");`

Comment: @aepot благодарю